# Urql cache invalidate is not removing items from the cache

Tags: graphql, svelte, urql

My application has a list of organizations and I have buttons in my UI to delete them individually.

I would like the list to update and remove the deleted organization but that is not working for me.

I have set up a cache exchange like this, where I have (redundantly) tried two cache invalidation methods from the Urql docs:

```
const cache = cacheExchange({
    updates: {
        Mutation: {
            delOrg(_result, args, cache, _info) {

                // Invalidate cache based on type
                cache.invalidate({ __typename: 'Org', id: args.id as number });

                // Invalidate all fields
                const key = 'Query';
                cache
                    .inspectFields(key)
                    .filter((field) => field.fieldName === 'allOrgs')
                    .forEach((field) => {
                        cache.invalidate(key, field.fieldKey);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The GraphQL query that returns the list of organizations looks like:

```
query AllOrgs {
    allOrgs {
        id
        name
        logo {
            id
            url
        }
    }
}
```

And the mutation to delete an organization looks like: (it returns a boolean)

```
mutation DelOrg($id: ID!) {
    delOrg(id: $id)
}
```

`cache.invalidate` does not appear to do anything. I have checked the cache using the debugging plugin as well as `console.log`.  I can see the records in the cache and they don't get removed.

I am using

```
"@urql/exchange-graphcache": "^4.4.1",
"@urql/svelte": "^1.3.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around my issue. I now use `cache.updateQuery` to update `data` rather than a single line, I now have -

```
updates: {
        Mutation: {
            delOrg(_result, args, cache, _info) {
                if (_result.delOrg) {
                    cache.updateQuery(
                        {
                            query: QUERY_ALL_ORGS
                        },

                        (data) => {
                            data = {
                                ...data,
                                allOrgs: data.allOrgs.filter((n) => n.id !== args.id)
                            };
                            return data;
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found another solution since then?

Comment: just the workaround listed here

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about **cache invalidation**, you can use the following `invalidateCache` function:

```js
const cacheConfig: GraphCacheConfig = {
    schema,
    updates: {
      Mutation: {
        // create
        createContact: (_parent, _args, cache, _info) =>
          invalidateCache(cache, 'allContacts'),

        // delete
        deleteContactById: (_parent, args, cache, _info) =>
          invalidateCache(cache, 'Contact', args),
      },
    },
  }

const invalidateCache = (
  cache: Cache,
  name: string,
  args?: { input: { id: any } }
) =>
  args
    ? cache.invalidate({ __typename: name, id: args.input.id })
    : cache
        .inspectFields('Query')
        .filter((field) => field.fieldName === name)
        .forEach((field) => {
          cache.invalidate('Query', field.fieldKey)
        })
```

For creation mutations - with no arguments - the function inspects the root `Query` and invalidates all field keys having matching field names.

For deletion mutations the function invalidates the key that must have been given as a mutation argument.